# Java Applet not working for any code in eclipse

Tags: java, graphics, applet

So i'm new to java coding (i started a few day's ago), i decided to start with the basics and make a rectangle, line or ellipse appear, i am Farley sure i wrote the code correctly but every time i tried to run the applet it would bring up this and say the applet in not initialized:

java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The public type Tutorial must be defined in its own file
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

```
at Tutorial.<init>(Applet101.java:4)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The code i'm using:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Tutorial extends JFrame 
{
      public Tutorial()
      {
             setTitle("Tutorial");
             setSize(400, 400);
             setVisible(true);
             setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      }

      public void paint(Graphics g)
      {
             g.drawRect(480, 480, 500, 100);
             g.fillRect(240, 240, 500, 100);
      }

       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
             Tutorial t = new Tutorial();
             t.paint(null); 
       }
}
```

So can you help with this problem?

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Tutorial extends JFrame
```

That's not an applet!  Change it to:

```
public class Tutorial extends JApplet
```

Also remove the entire constructor (none of the code in it is relevant to an applet) and the `main(String[]` which is not used for an applet.

Answer (score 0):

This link can help you.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/applet_create.htm

and

Applet has init, start, stop, destroy.
at and you must sign your applet to run in browsers.